# BM_SETCHECK does not check a radio button

Tags: winapi, checkbox, radio-button

I am calling this method:

```
Helpers.WinApi.SendMessage(nextControl, Helpers.WinApi.BM_SETCHECK, Helpers.WinApi.BST_CHECKED, new StringBuilder());
```

Where: BM_SETCHECK constant is 0x00F1 and BST_CHECKED is 1.

This message is totally ignored.

How can I do it? 
Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Why are you passing a `StringBuilder` in the `lParam` parameter?  `BM_SETCHECK` does not use `lParam`, it should be 0. In any case, what is the return value of `SendMessage()`? If the message is being ignored, then the likely culprit is `nextControl` is not actually pointing at a check/radio button to begin with. You can verify that with `GetClassName()` to make sure the class name is `BUTTON`, and `GetWindowLong(GWL_STYLE)` to make sure the button has a `BS_RADIOBUTTON` style.

Comment: I am using StringBuilder because I am sending strings as that parameter to SendMessage in other methods.... I have read that for BM_SETCHECK, that parameter is just ignored. However, I have changed the SendMessage definition momentarily to be able to send a zero  in that parameter, but the radio button was not checked either. I know that this is the radio button I need to check because I have used Spy++ to verify this.

Comment: I have read also that SendMessage for BM_SETCHECK returns always 0 and when I use Spy++, the class for this control is WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r14_ad1. It is a radio button created in a Winforms C# application

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have got the style with GetWindowLong and it is 0x5601000B. With that, I know that BS_RADIOBUTON = 0x0004 is not set. How can this be? it is a RadioButton created in a Window form using C#.

Comment: that value is a combination of the following styles: `WS_TABSTOP`, `WS_CLIPCHILDREN`, `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`, `WS_CHILD`, `WS_VISIBLE`, and `BS_OWNERDRAW`. Note the last one. It means the radio button is not a true radio button from the Win32 API's perspective, which explains why `BM_SETCHECK` does not work. It is a custom drawn button instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by sending a BM_CLICK message to the control.